# Pick document and gallery images with same picker

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I can pick gallery images with `UIImagePickerController` and documents with `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. But my question is, is there any way to pick gallery image and pdf documents with same picker?

I have tried `UIDocumentPickerViewController` with `documentTypes` as `kUTTypePDF` and `kUTTypeImage`. But it only opens the files directory with iCloud drive and on my iPhone directory.

```
let docPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String, kUTTypeImage as String], in: .import)
```

Is there any way I can pick both gallery or camera roll images and pdf documents with one picker?